# How to test an iPhone app on a device for the first time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-provisioning

I am developing an app for iPhone. How can I test this app on my device?

What are the procedures to follow? Please give information regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you will need are

1. your private key.
2. your provisioning profile (with the UUID of your device added).
3. go to project settings and change code signing entity to your
   distribution profile.

then you can build and run after connecting your device.

Answer (score 9):

**Deploying iPhone Apps to Real Devices** 
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

In brief:

- Sign up for the iPhone Developer Program
- Obtain an iPhone Development Certificate
- Generate a Certificate Signing Request
- Generate, download and install your provisioning profile
- Download and install your Development Certificate
- Deploy your iPhone application.

Comment: That really is a comprehensive guide.

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Open Xcode,

2) Go to Active SDK, and select the OS version running on your test device (viewable by going to Settings->General->About on the device).

3) With your project open, click on "Build and Run" (or press Command-R) to run the project, which will prompt you to allow access to your keychain.

4) Once deployed, the app will run automatically.
Distribution

Comment: And a lot of stuff that takes twenty times a long as those 4 steps need to be done before 1). UUIDs, App Ids, Developer Keys, Certificates and so on.

Comment: these id how to create? and where to put?which oder to create these id?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to run the app on your phisical device you must enroll to the **apple developer program**.
Second, generate a developer certificate and download it. Then, import the certificate into Xcode and here you go.

Comment: thanks, now i create certificate.but while running the app in device ios provisioning profile error display.what i do?

Comment: 1) add your device to the provising profile
2) re-download that provising profile (devel or distribution)

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps you need to follow to test your app on your personal iPhone. Below you can find all the steps:

- Creat MAC certificate at first step.
- Second step is to upload that certificate to developer account.
- Now you should open developer account at
  http://www.developer.apple.com
- You can now find an option for device id in your developer account on
  left side.
- Now you should register your iphone device.
- It is time to create your unique identifier on developer account
- Download your certificate and install it on xcode organize
- Now open your project embed your unique identifier in your project.

These steps can be beneficial for all software testing gusy involved in mobile application testing.